# Making ListView clickable after being filtered by TextWatcher

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-adapter, android-textwatcher

I am pulling data from a SQLite database and storing it in an arrayList to display info on the contact through listView. The user can then type in an EditText and the TextWatcher filters the listView. But, when this happens the position of the listview items do not update in my onClickListener.

The ID I send to my CRUD activity is always the position after they have been filtered not their position when originally listed. How can I make my ListView items hold their original position after they have been filtered? Or a better way to give my CRUD activity the correct ID not via position.

```
    public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;


 // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    DBHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        db = new DBHelper(this);

        arrayList = db.getAllContacts();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Search.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {


                        int id_To_Search = pos + 1;

                        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                        dataBundle.putInt(EXTRA_FLAG, id_To_Search);
                        // The flag value > 0 is used to signal that the upcoming operation
                        // is not adding, but updating or deleting

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CRUDActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtras(dataBundle);  //Intent.putExtras(Bundle extras
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: Setting onItemClickListener inside onTextChange doesn't make sense. Position is not id. You can only get text from ArrayList inside onItemClick using the common way to get "clicked" element(and no, it's not arrayList.get(pos) as pos points to new filtered list, the common way is to use parent parameter of onItemClick - easy to find with Internet search)

Comment: @Slevin Thank you!

Comment: For what? It was just few hints...

Comment: @Selvin It's better than nothing at all. I know the position is not ID I am looking for a way to have the unfiltered listview remember where the position of the item was when before it was filtered.Then have the filtered items pass their original position to my CRUD activity after they have been filtered

Comment: parent.getItemAtPosition(pos) cast to string. Find index of this string in original ArrayList... But there is a better way

Comment: @Selvin Again thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a second array and then splitting it, compared it to the item selected, and then parsed the id from a String to an int. After that, I sent to id to my Crud activity so it could populate the contact searched.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

            String split = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            // Split this into sections then compare the name with arrayList2, then take the ID from arratList2
            // parse it to an int and set it as the ID to search
            int id_To_Search = 0;
            String array[] = split.split(" ");


            for ( int i = 0; i < arrayList2.size(); i++) {
                String split2[] =  arrayList2.get(i).split(" ");

                if (split2[1].equals(array[0])) {
                    //print item the same way as you did
                   id_To_Search = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
                }
            }


            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt(EXTRA_FLAG, id_To_Search);
            // The flag value > 0 is used to signal that the upcoming operation
            // is not adding, but updating or deleting

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CRUDActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);  //Intent.putExtras(Bundle extras
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
```